# Send "Here I am now" location report in a Messages.app thread on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, messages, geolocation

In iOS, we can send our current location as a message within a discussion thread on [Messages.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messages_(Apple)).

➥ Can this be done in Messages.app on a Mac in [Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) or [Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina)?

I am *not* asking about people already actively sharing their location on an ongoing basis. I am looking for the "Here I am right now" post of current location offered in iOS. The result is a fixed location, an unchanging report. In iOS it presents as an item in the Messages thread, with a map and pin-drop. The user can tap to be taken to the Maps app with that location.

Answer (score 3):

Yes location can be seen on Mac, but needs to be enabled on iOS.

> Friends can share their location through the Messages or Find My Friends app on an iOS device. You can see the location they shared on a map in Messages.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/messages/icht18df1a6a/12.0/mac/10.14
 landed here from macOS help menu.

**Otherwise**, pin drop can be done in Maps app and that can shared using messages. To do this:

Go to Maps on the Mac, click on the Show your current location arrow, click on the Share icon and then select Messages. A popup then appears for you to select your recipient(s) and they're sent a message starting with My location followed by a URL followed by a static image of your location. The recipient can look at the image of your location, or they can tap on the link and that'll open Maps on their device with your location and directions to get there.

Comment: That feature is for people already actively sharing their location on an ongoing basis. I am looking for the "Here I am right now" post of current location. It is a fixed location, unchanging report. In iOS it presents as an item in the Messages thread, with a map and pin-drop. The user can tap to be taken to the Maps app with that location. I edited the Question to be more clear and specific.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting your question, but isn't what you're after effectively what the last sentence in ankiiiiiii's answer is about? Go to Maps on the Mac, click on the Show your current location arrow, click on the Share icon and then select Messages. A popup then appears for you to select your recipient(s) and they're sent a message starting with *My location* followed by a URL followed by a static image of your location. The recipient can look at the image of your location, or they can tap on the link and that'll open Maps on their device with your location and directions to get there.

Comment: @Monomeeth mind if I use this comment as it is in my answer? Thanks for the workflow!

Comment: Absolutely! I was about to edit it into your answer anyway! So please, go ahead. :)